# Diagonalizing a symbolic matrix using SymPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-algebra, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a symbolic matrix that I would like to diagonalize to find its eigenvalues. I used the SymPy `diagonalize` function, but my code doesnt complete even after running for two hours. No error is given, it just doesn't terminate. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702271/diagonalize-symbolic-matrix) uses the similar protocol but completes immediately. Does anybody know why this would not complete?

```
import sympy
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import *

J1 = Symbol('J1')
J2= Symbol('J2')
S1 = Symbol('S1')
S2 = Symbol('S2')
S3 = Symbol('S3')
S4 = Symbol('S4')

Alistmatrix=sympy.Matrix([[0, -2*J1*S1*S2, -J2*S1*S3, 0],
[-2*J1*S1*S2, 0, -2*J1*S2*S3, -J2*S2*S4],
[-J2*S1*S3, -2*J1*S2*S3, 0, -2*J1*S3*S4],
[0, -J2*S2*S4, -2*J1*S3*S4, 0]])


print (Alistmatrix.eigenvects())
print (Alistmatrix.eigenvals())
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a huge difference in complexity between diagonalizing a 2 by 2 matrix and a 4 by 4 matrix. In fact, `Alistmatrix.eigenvals()` returns four eigenvalues, the first of which is:

```
{Piecewise((-sqrt(8*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S1**2*S3**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S2**2*S4**2/3 - 2*(-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**(1/3))/2 + sqrt(16*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2/3 + 16*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2/3 + 16*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2/3 + 4*J2**2*S1**2*S3**2/3 + 4*J2**2*S2**2*S4**2/3 + (16*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 16*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)/sqrt(8*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S1**2*S3**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S2**2*S4**2/3 - 2*(-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**(1/3)) + 2*(-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**(1/3))/2, Eq(-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12, 0)), (-sqrt(8*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S1**2*S3**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S2**2*S4**2/3 - 2*(-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)/(3*((8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/16 + sqrt((-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**2/4 + (-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)**3/27) - (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/6 + (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/216)**(1/3)) + 2*((8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/16 + sqrt((-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**2/4 + (-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)**3/27) - (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/6 + (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/216)**(1/3))/2 + sqrt(16*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2/3 + 16*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2/3 + 16*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2/3 + 4*J2**2*S1**2*S3**2/3 + 4*J2**2*S2**2*S4**2/3 + (16*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 16*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)/sqrt(8*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2/3 + 8*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S1**2*S3**2/3 + 2*J2**2*S2**2*S4**2/3 - 2*(-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)/(3*((8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/16 + sqrt((-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**2/4 + (-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)**3/27) - (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/6 + (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/216)**(1/3)) + 2*((8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/16 + sqrt((-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**2/4 + (-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)**3/27) - (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/6 + (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/216)**(1/3)) + 2*(-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)/(3*((8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/16 + sqrt((-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**2/4 + (-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)**3/27) - (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/6 + (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/216)**(1/3)) - 2*((8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/16 + sqrt((-(8*J1**2*J2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2 + 8*J1**2*J2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)**2/8 + (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/3 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/108)**2/4 + (-16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**2/12)**3/27) - (16*J1**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 - 8*J1**2*J2**2*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2 + J2**4*S1**2*S2**2*S3**2*S4**2)*(-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)/6 + (-4*J1**2*S1**2*S2**2 - 4*J1**2*S2**2*S3**2 - 4*J1**2*S3**2*S4**2 - J2**2*S1**2*S3**2 - J2**2*S2**2*S4**2)**3/216)**(1/3))/2, True)): 1, ...
```

Scroll to the right to fully appreciate this formula. I could not paste the entire output of `eigenvals` here, as it exceeds the Stack Overflow post limit.

So it's little surprise that `eigenvects()` subsequently chokes, as it has to find eigenvectors for eigenvalues of that complexity, which are Piecewise on top of all.

Perhaps the right thing to do here is to step back and ask: what would you do with a 38000-character formula for eigenvalues even if it was accompanied by a 200000-character formula for eigenvectors? Some problems are just not meant to be solved symbolically.